# Object detection with domain adaptation using TIA: Why is my model returning multiple bounding boxes for a single object?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, object-detection, faster-rcnn

I'm doing domain adaptation object detection using https://github.com/MCG-NJU/TIA, the code is based on Faster-RCNN (https://github.com/jwyang/faster-rcnn.pytorch/tree/pytorch-1.0). Working on a custom dataset the model returns a high number of bounding boxes for each detected object and in most of the cases there is no bounding containing the entire object but instead many small ones.

[Ex 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxtwq.png) [Ex 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLc6t.png)

I tried training the model using normal Faster-RCNN (without domain adaptation) with the same configurations as the one used in TIA and this problem doesn't arise.